# Consider the set of all $n\times n$ matrices, how many of them are invertible modulo $p$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Groups/Linear maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/groups-linear-maps)

Given a natural number $n$, consider the set of all $n\times n$ matrices where each element is a member of $\mathbb Z_p$, where $p $ is a prime.

How many of these matrices are invertible modulo $p$?

Comment: This is more or less the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64454/counting-automorphisms/64455#64455.

Comment: This is the Gaussian Binomial Coefficient, $\displaystyle \binom n 0_p$

Comment: ${\rm GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields

Comment: Answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/groups-linear-maps

Comment: The same idea from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/116216/742) works as well.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is Theorem 2.1.1 in the following [PDF notes](http://jeff.over.bz/papers/undergrad/on-the-keyspace-of-the-hill-cipher.pdf):
$$ | {\rm GL}(n, \mathbb{Z}_p) | = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (p^n- p^i) $$

You can learn more about ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields).